# Mathf.Mathf.Approximately does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code for moving a fog sprite that passes trough the game and changes the background. The thing is that Mathf.Approximately does not return true. Any ideas why this is happening or how can I work around this without hard coding the position values.

```
 fog.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(fog.transform.position.x,gameObject.transform.position.x,transitionTime * Time.deltaTime),
                                                                                                                 gameObject.transform.position.y, 0f);

        if (Mathf.Approximately(fog.transform.position.x, backGround.transform.position.x))
        {
            index++;
            currentBackround.sprite = enviroments[index];
            Debug.Log(index);
        }
        if (Mathf.Approximately(fog.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.x))
        {
            fog.transform.position = startPos;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling these statements? In the `Update()` method?

Comment: @Unai . Yes in the update method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by writing my own approximation, but I'm still interested in why Mathf.Approximately does not work. Here is the code that I wrote

```
private bool myApproximation(float a, float b, float tolerance)
    {
        return (Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance);
    }
```

Comment: Unity's `Mathf.Approximately` does work, but its tolerance is both small and undocumented, which is not always ideal. I usually prefer to write my own function, which ends up looking a lot like yours.

Comment: My understanding was that the tolerance of Mathf.Approximately is Mathf.epsilon, the smallest non-zero value a float can have. But yes, that's often too small for ones needs.

Comment: This is how unity implements it , in case any one interested                                                                                           `public static bool Approximately (float a, float b)
{
 return Mathf.Abs (b - a) < Mathf.Max (1E-06f * Mathf.Max (Mathf.Abs (a), Mathf.Abs (b)), 1.121039E-44f);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that `Mathf.Approximately` does not return true because in fact the two values are not the same when this method is called.

This is caused because you call `Mathf.Approximately` in the `Update` method, which is called every `Time.deltaTime`. So if in these exactly moments the values are not the same, `Mathf.Approximately` won't return true.

It's like if you were watching someone counting numbers and he shows the number you're expecting when you blinks. You can't know that this number has been counted.

Comment: wait wait. Matf.Approximately is supposed to APPROXIMATE equality. Its not just a == operation. Even if that is the case why does myApproximation work and Matf's does not

Comment: Maybe the threshold is too tiny to return true. What tolerance are you using in your method `myApproximation`