# C# mod fails in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am performing the following, but instead of `zRem` having the expected value of zero I get 2.384186E-07:

```
Vector3 t = this.transform.position - _startPosition;
float xRem = t.x % 1;
float zRem = t.z % 1;
```

In this instance:

```
this.transform.position = 2.5, 0, 3.5
_startPosition = 1.5, 0, 1.5
```

`xRem` is correct, but `zRem` have the value 2.384186E-07.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**UPDATE #1**:
When using the values above it should not enter this block, but because of `zRem` it does.

```
if(!Mathf.Approximately(xRem, 0f) || !Mathf.Approximately(zRem, 0f))
{
     return;
}
```

Comment: Tried it here, it works fine.. More information please?

Comment: What would you expect it to be? 3.5 - 1.5 = 2, 2 % 1 = 0, and 2.384186E-07 is a very small number. Have you tried it using double?

Comment: I an expected a value of zero. If I created a Vector3 with the hard-coded values it works. I have inspected the `t` variable and all values are correct, but the calculation fails.

Comment: Floats are rarely actually equal to zero. Use `Float.Epsilon` for "zero" comparisons where necessary. Though, I'm not exactly sure why you're getting a problem with such low-precision values.

Comment: I have added an example how I use and compare these variables.

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of this.transform.position and _startPosition before doing the calculations? There is nothing else fiddling with the position of the object?

Comment: Posible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471464/mathf-mathf-approximately-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Well, mod is not failing... Float point arithmetics always involve some level of precision/error.

I know, Mathf.Aproximately is meant to take ilthis into account, but Unity have its own Epsilon value for comparing floats and, guess what, it's value isn't documented.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html

(Maybe it is system dependent, according to the representation model of float values. Maybe it's IEEE conformant, I don't know)

Thing is: you should define what threshold use that conforms with your game logic, something like this:

```
if(xRem <= threshold)
```

Or

```
if(Mathf.abs(xRem) <= threshold)
```