# Unity C# Vector3.Distance produces unexpected result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting an unexpected result from [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) function, could someone please explain what is going on here:

I create two vectors using two angles and a radius, when angles are 0 and 360 degrees, I expected the distance to be 0, but it is not. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
public float angle1 = 0f;
public float angle2 = 360f;
public float radius = 1f;
private Vector3 position1, position2;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // calculate position vector from given angle
    position1 = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle1), Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle1)) * radius;
    position2 = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle2), Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle2)) * radius;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(position1, position2);

    print("angle1: " + angle1 + " angle2: " + angle2);
    print("pos1: " + position1 + " pos2: " + position2);
    print("positions equal: " + (position1 == position2));
    print("distance: " + distance);
   }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
angle1: 0 angle2: 360
pos1: (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) pos2: (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
positions equal: True
distance: 1.748456E-07
```

Any help is apprecited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite unexpected. It is just how the data type `float` can operate at times due to [`floating point precision`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise). You would want to compare the values using an epsilon or by using a function built into unity called [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html), which is equivalent to an epsilon check.

Based on Unity's docs of [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html), the implementation is the same as the magnitude of the difference of two vectors. From your example, the result would clearly be `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, and the magnitude should be `√(x^2+y^2+z^2)`, which would be `√(0)` or just `0`. Now, the answer that `Vector.Distance` has outputted is `1.748456E-07`, or `1.748456*(10^-07)`, which is `0.000000175`. If we use `Mathf.Approximately` using `0`, your expected answer and the answer the function gave you, `0.000000175`, the are approximately the same value.

Edit: Just tested it and whatever epsilon that Unity uses for `Mathf.Approximately` is [`smaller than`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599418/is-mathf-approximately0-0f-float-epsilon-true-its-correct-behavior) `0.000000175`, so it actually returns false. The reason as to why it returns such a value would still stand though.

Comment: You can simply look at the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L284) and see that Unity uses some strange construct `Abs(b - a) < Max(0.000001f * Max(Abs(a), Abs(b)), Epsilon * 8)` where Epsilon is either `1.17549435E-38f` or `Single.Epsilon` (=`1.401298E-45`) depending on the system ;)

Comment: @derHugo Interesting wasn't aware it was available. Very odd indeed. Bookmarked - thanks for the resource!