# Trying to understand Mathf.Approximately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, precision, equality

Can someone give a simplest example, when `Mathf.Approximately` gives true?

A try the following and  it is always false:

```
Debug.Log(Mathf.Approximately(0.0001f, 0.0f));  // False
Debug.Log(Mathf.Approximately(0.00000001f, 0.0f));  // False
Debug.Log(Mathf.Approximately(0.00000000000001f, 0.0f));  // False
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599418/is-mathf-approximately0-0f-float-epsilon-true-its-correct-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) says that they're equal if they are "within a very small value (epsilon)".

Epsilon [is documented](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) as "the smallest value a float can have different from zero".

How small is that? `FloatMinNormal` or `FloatMinDenormal` depending on `IsFlushToZeroEnabled`, which as you can see [from source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L15) would be about 1e-38, *much* smaller than `0.00000000000001f`.

For non-zero values, the exact computation depends on the order of magnitude of the numbers, [you can check out the source code for the precise formula](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L281-L288).

Some numbers (e.g. 0.1) can't be represented *exactly* with a float. This is why `Approximately` can be more useful than straight equality. It is a complex topic, though, that needs more than a SO answer to fully develop. If you want to learn more, maybe start there: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thank you, that made this topic a little clearer for me.