# How can I get as much as close to 0 on float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var f = anim.GetFloat("Forward");

        if(distance > 61f && anim.GetFloat("Forward") == 0.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("HumanIdle");
            anim.SetFloat("JumpLeg", 0.0f);
        }
```

I added the variable f just for testing.
The value of f is : 0.003943384 so it will never pass the IF check.

but I don't want to check for 0.1f or 1.0f but like it is now 0.003943384 but doing just :

```
if(distance > 61f && anim.GetFloat("Forward") == 0.003943384f)
```

Does not mean the result will be all the time 0.003943384 how can I check for as much as closer to 0.003943384 ?

This is a script attached to the Player :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject distanceTarget;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;

    private Animator anim;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 3;
    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp = 0;

    // Opposite Direction
    float timeElapsedOpposite = 0;
    float lerpDurationOpposite = 3;
    float startValueForOpposite = 0;
    float endValueForOpposite = 1;
    float valueToLerpOpposite = 0;   

    float angle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, distanceTarget.transform.position);
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        if (distance >= 61f && angle < 180)
        {
            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);

            timeElapsedOpposite = 0;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            text.text = "I can't move that far by foot. I need to find some transportation to move any further.";
        }
        else
        {
            text.text = "";
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Get the angle:
        
        if (angle > 180f && distance >= 61f)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("JumpLeg", 0.0f);

            if (timeElapsedOpposite < lerpDurationOpposite)
            {
                valueToLerpOpposite = Mathf.Lerp(startValueForOpposite, endValueForOpposite, timeElapsedOpposite / lerpDurationOpposite);
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerpOpposite);
                timeElapsedOpposite += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerpOpposite);

            timeElapsed = 0;
        }

        var f = anim.GetFloat("Forward");

        if(distance > 61f && anim.GetFloat("Forward") == 0.0f)
        {
            anim.Play("HumanIdle");
            anim.SetFloat("JumpLeg", 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

In the bottom of the script I'm checking if the parameter Forward value is 0.0

In this part I'm checking the player facing direction and then slowly changing the Forward parameter value from 1 to 0 :

```
if (distance >= 61f && angle < 180)
```

Then at the bottom I want to check when the player is at distance more then 61 and that is true and also if he stopped Forward == 0.0 then do the stuff inside.

But Forward is never 0.0 even if in the editor animator controller it's showing that Forward is 0.0 :

[image: In editor]

In the editor it's 0.0 but in the script it's

```
var f = anim.GetFloat("Forward");
```

0.003943384f

So instead checking against 0.0 I want to check to something closer to 0.0 something around 0.003943384f because I can't be sure if it will ever be all the cases 0.003943384f value so something close to it.

Comment: What values can `anim.GetFloat("Forward")` be that it should be true? question very unclear. Please edit.

Comment: [Does this answer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28471600/1092820)

Comment: @Ruzihm In the editor in the animator controller the parameter Forward is 0.0 when I'm checking it in the script it's not really 0.0f like in the editor show but 0.003943384 so around 0.003943384 is good enough.  If ion the editor it show 0.0 and in the script 0.003943384 then I don't mind if it will not check for exactly 0.0 0.003943384 is enough.

Comment: This sounds like a semantic issue.  You're seeing 0.0 displayed, but actual value is 0.004.  Since you're the one setting the value, I'm not sure what you're not sure about...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.Ceiling()`

```
float result = Math.Ceiling(yourValue);
```

It will round your result so you could work on the new rounded value

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

If you're wanting near-equality, use [`Mathf.Approximately()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
var isNearEqual = Mathf.Approximately( anim.GetFloat("Forward"), 0.003943384f );
```

If you're wanting whether the value is nearer to zero, use `Mathf.Abs()`

```
var isNearerZero  = Mathf.Abs( anim.GetFloat("Forward") ) < 0.003943384f;
```

---

If you're wanting near-equality but in a wider band, use

```
const EqualityMargin = Mathf.Epsilon; // Or some other deviation you'd prefer
var isAlmostEqual = Mathf.Abs( anim.GetFloat("Forward") - 0.003943384f ) <= EqualityMargin;
```